# Finding x amount of points in a three dimensional line? (from 2 3d point objects) in Java

Tags: java, math, 3d

So i am using the Java [Point3D](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/geometry/Point3D.html) object. I am wondering the best way to get X amount of points between two 3d points in space.

```
Point3D a = new Point3D(0, 0, 0);
Point3D b = new Point3D(1, 4, 9);
int count = 30  //Used to set how many points to represent the line

//This would return a list of points that represent the line
Point3D[] pointsBetween(a, b, count);
```

Would this be best achieved with vectors? I am also running this pretty heavily, so i am looking for the most efficient way to calculate this. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding coordinates of a point between two points?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886092/finding-coordinates-of-a-point-between-two-points)

Comment: Line has infinite number of points so did you mean segments of defined length or pixels or voxels instead? in Case of pixels or voxels there are usually some projections and aligning to grid applied so you need to take that into account too. You should edit your **Q/A** and clarify so others are not confused. Also @Andreas is right if your answer is the right solution for your problem (even if it is your own) you should accept it (click on the checker under vote count) so  others see that this is solved and how.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was vectors, Simply get a vector from point a to point b, then add in that direction (add divided by the amount of steps or count)

Comment: If you think this question and answer can benefit others, then please accept your own answer. Otherwise please delete the question.