# Is there a way to get an average "range" between two points in pymel?

Tags: math, curve, pymel

The title may be a bit confusing, so let me put it this way:

I have a polygon strip at a tilted angle, I want to add a curve(in a straight line) that goes through the strip, from start to end, and stays centered in the strip.

I can get the starting point, middle point and endpoint of the strip with the use of these variables:

startPos = polygonStrip.getTranslation() # I've moved the pivot point to be at the base of the strip. This variable is where I want the curve to start.

centerXCoord = pm.objectCenter(polygonStrip,x=True) #this variable gets the center of the strip.

endPos = centerXCoord + (startPos[0]/2) # this variable gets the endpoint. This is where I want the curve to end.

Basically, I want to find a way for all of the curve points to fall between the start and end points evenly so they form a tilted but straight line between them.  I've got the Y and Z values working, it's just X that is giving me trouble.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thank you!

[Image to help visualize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSUDd.png)

Answer (score 0):

To summarize you have:

- a start position (the coords of the start of you strip)
- a mid position (coords of the "center" of you strip)
- a end position (coords of the end point of you strip)
- the number of points you want on your curve *(this is something you didn't mention but it's cool if you want to add more precision)*

With these parameters we can compute points coords along your strip, to do that we will use a [very basic math formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886092/finding-coordinates-of-a-point-between-two-points) :

```py
# start_point and end_point are 3D point (X,Y,Z)
# ratio_val is a float value between 0.0 and 1.0
start_point + ratio_val(end_point - start_point)
```

In the function I made below I added multiple **[early return](https://dev.to/jpswade/return-early-12o5)** to avoid unnecessary calculation. I also a lot of comments so you can follow along what the function is doing.

```py
def getCurvePointsCoords(strip_start_pos, strip_mid_pos, strip_end_pos, curve_points_num):
    """Compute the 3D points that constitute the curve

    Args:
        strip_start_pos: 3D starting point of the strip
        strip_mid_pos: 3D middle point of the strip
        strip_end_pos: 3D ending point of the strip
        curve_points_num: Number of points that constitute the curve

    Returns:
        The list of 3D

    """
    if curve_points_num < 2:
        # A valid curve cannot have less than 2 points
        # Maybe raise an exception or print an error /!\
        return []

    if curve_points_num == 2:
        # Only two points, no calculation necessary
        return [strip_start_pos, strip_end_pos]

    if curve_points_num == 3:
        # Only three points, no calculation necessary
        return [strip_start_pos, strip_mid_pos, strip_end_pos]

    curve_mid_value = (curve_points_num - 1) * 0.5
    check_mid_point = curve_mid_value.is_integer()

    # Create the list that we will populate below
    curve_points_coords = []

    # Add the curve start point
    curve_points_coords.append(strip_start_pos)

    # Compute coords of intermediaries points
    for point_index in range(1, (curve_points_num - 1)):
        if check_mid_point and point_index == int(curve_mid_value):
            # The current point is perfectly in the middle of the curve
            curve_points_coords.append(strip_mid_pos)
        elif point_index < curve_mid_value:
            # Point is on the first portion (between strip_start_pos and strip_mid_pos)
            point_pos_ratio = point_index / curve_mid_value
            # Equation is: start_point + ratio_val(end_point - start_point)
            point_coords = strip_start_pos + point_pos_ratio * (strip_mid_pos - strip_start_pos)
            curve_points_coords.append(point_coords)
        else:
            # Point is on the second portion (between strip_mid_pos and strip_end_pos)
            point_pos_ratio = (point_index - curve_mid_value) / curve_mid_value
            # Equation is: start_point + ratio_val(end_point - start_point)
            point_coords = strip_mid_pos + point_pos_ratio * (strip_end_pos - strip_mid_pos)
            curve_points_coords.append(point_coords)

    # Add curve ending point
    curve_points_coords.append(strip_end_pos)

    return curve_points_coords
```

This is a pure Python function, this means that it work with numpy but also pymel vector (or 3D points).